# Sorting array of objects by object variable, key being replaced

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have got an array of object instances, I need to sort these based on what a function within the object returns.

So basically my object has got 2 variables, the function will add them together, and then return the result, the list of objects need to be sorted based on this.

My sorting code:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
  if ($a->calcPoints() == $b->calcPoints()) {
     return 0;
  }
  return ($a->calcPoints() > $b->calcPoints()) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($teamData, "cmp");
```

Without using the usort function I get the following when dumping my array:

> Key: "Hull City FC" Value:
>   {"win":3,"draw":2,"loss":8,"goalFor":11,"goalConc":28} Key: "Leicester
>   City FC" Value: {"win":3,"draw":4,"loss":6,"goalFor":16,"goalConc":22}

Once I used the usort function, my keys are being replaced like so:

> Key: 0 Value: {"win":10,"draw":1,"loss":2,"goalFor":29,"goalConc":10}
>   Key: 1 Value: {"win":9,"draw":3,"loss":1,"goalFor":29,"goalConc":12}

How can I stop this?

Comment: Have you tried using [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you lookup [`usort()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) in the manual, you'll find:

> **Note:** This function assigns new keys to the elements in array. It will remove any existing keys that may have been assigned, rather than
>   just reordering the keys.

[`uasort()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php), however, will: "Sort an array with a user-defined comparison function and maintain index association". Go ahead and try that, it should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `uasort` function instead of `usort`. According to [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php):

> uasort — Sort an array with a user-defined comparison function **and
>   maintain index association**